# SQL таблица ссылается сама на себя. Какая схема БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Имеются сущности: 
    1) ЮЛ (юридическое лицо, компания) со свойствами: Наименование, ИНН, ОГРН;
    2) ФЛ (физическое лицо, персона) со свойствами: ФИО, ИНН

Между этими сущностями возможны связи "Учредил", характеризующиеся свойством "доля". У ЮЛ может быть несколько учредителей, которые могут быть как ФЛ, так и ЮЛ. 
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какая схема БД, подходит для хранения экземпляров указанных сущностей и связей;

Answer (score 4):

Я бы делал так.

Первая таблица с юриками (UL)

Вторая таблица с физиками (FL)

И две таблицы со связями (LINKS_UL, LINKS_FL)

```
create table LINKS_UL(
    id int foreign key UL(id),
    related int foreign key UL(id)
)

create table LINKS_FL(
    id int foreign key UL(id),
    related int foreign key FL(id)
)
```

Но вообще многое зависит от того, как пользоваться данными планируете

Answer (score 1):

Юридические и физические лица - это одна и та же сущность "субъекты права". По крайней мере у них много общего. Исходя из этого можно сделать такую структуру:

1. Субъекты права: ID субъекта, Тип субъекта (ФЛ/ЮЛ), Наименование (ФИО если ФЛ), ИНН, прочие общие поля
2. Юридические лица: своего ID нет, первичный ключ - ссылка на ID из "субъекты" связь один к одному. Плюс специализированные поля ЮЛ, аналога которым у ФЛ нет.
3. Учредители: ID субъекта ЮЛ - внешний ключ ссылающийся на ID-субъекта из таблицы юридических лиц, ID-учредителя - внешний ключ, ссылающийся на ID-субъекта из таблицы "Субъекты права", первичный ключ составной из этих двух полей. Плюс прочие поля вроде доли в уставном капитале и т.п.

При желании/необходимости для физических лиц заводите дополнительную таблицу по аналогии с юриками. Т.е. со связью 1-к-1 с таблицей субъектов